# Using derived subquery result in an other query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to use first subquery result in next select. But it does not see row1 as it is not a table in database. How can I solve this problem?

```
UPDATE transactions, (SELECT
                    card_id,
                    id,
                    card_sum_before,
                    card_sum_after,
                    amount,
                    dt
                  FROM transactions
                  WHERE status = 1 AND
                        card_id = 1
                  ORDER BY dt ASC) AS counted_table,
  (SELECT
 row2.id                                                   AS id,
 (row1.card_sum_after - row2.amount - row2.card_sum_after) AS difference
FROM counted_table AS row1
 INNER JOIN counted_table AS row2 ON row2.id = row1.id + 1
ORDER BY row1.dt ASC) selected
SET transactions.difference = selected.difference
WHERE transactions.id = selected.id`
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please provide sample table structure and data

Answer (score 0):

Please do something like, Store first query output to temp table and then use that temp table in any query you want.